# Player Car Runtime Scaling Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a car as my main player and as you destroy other cars, your car size gets increased during gameplay so you become stronger to destroy other enemy cars.

Now when I scale up runtime player car, it started giving me this kind of problem:
[image]

As the car scale increased, the car started going inside the ground, above image represented this point clearly. 
Now what to do for the solution? So the car does not get inside the ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of pivot which is in the center of car. I guess you have some sort of offset from the ground for every car's model. You should scale this offset as well. So let's say you have some offset when you're spawning car. Then when you're scaling your car you should also correct its position.

```
transform.position = transform.position + offset * (transform.localScale.y - prevYScale);
```

It is also worth to consider if moving pivot to the point where car should stick to the ground isn't a good idea in your case. You wouldn't need any corrections then.

Answer (score 0):

You scale from center of your car player.

The easiest way to solve it is creating another `GameObject` in the Hierarchy window and make it parent of you car player, then move the car player `Transform` so that the center of the parent's `Transform` is just below the car.

Then you should scale the parent instead of the car player, this will scale the car player only on top of the road.